# Ansible - get nested variable using hostname

Tags: ansible

I have a requirement to get values from some nested variables based on the current host `inventory_hostname`. These are not `hostvars`.
I've tried with the `lookup plugin` but no luck.

```
- name: Test
  hosts: server1
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    xyz:
      server1:
        - abc: 7
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars','xyz').inventory_hostname }}"
```

The `"{{ lookup('vars','xyz').server1 }}"` is working though!
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your provided example I understand that you probably like to do

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    LOCAL:
      localhost:
        - abc: 7

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ LOCAL[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - abc: 7
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to look them up.
Just call them i.e. `hostvars[inventory_hostname].inventory_hostname_short`, but change the variables into dictionary.

```yaml
- name: Test
  hosts: server1
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    xyz:
      server1:
        abc: 7
      server2:
        abc: 8
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ xyz[inventory_hostname].abc }}"
```